# Is it possible detect single enterkey with java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a terminal-based toy app, which allows user to input product category and inventory.

Is it possible to implement a feature of pressing enter key to input the default inventory.

Here is the procedure/steps

1. app print "product category:"
2. user input a category, such as shoe
3. app print "Inventory(press enter key for 999):"
4. user press enterkey or input another number
5. app print product_category + product_inventory

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("product category: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String product_category = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Inventory(press enter key for 999): ");
        int product_inventory = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s, %d", product_category, product_inventory));
    }

}
```

this code does not support "enterkey for default" feature.

## quesion

is it possible detect single enterkey with java.util.Scanner to implement the default input?

I also tried this code, even worse

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ProductScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("product category: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String product_category = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();
        System.out.print("Inventory(press enter key for 999): ");
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String product_inventory_str = "999";
        if(scanner.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("hasNext");
            product_inventory_str = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("does not have Next");
        }

        int product_inventory = 999;
        if(product_inventory_str.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("isEmpty");
        }
        else{
            product_inventory = Integer.parseInt(product_inventory_str);
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s, %d", product_category, product_inventory));
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNext()`.

Comment: For your purpose, what you want is for the user to enter an empty string, or a code. So you should check `hasNextLine()` and use `nextLine`. If the line is empty - that's your "enter key only". If the line is not empty, you parse it into a number for the code. Remember that if you use any `nextXXX()` to follow it with a `nextLine()` otherwise your next `nextLine()` will capture the "enter" from the end of that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always read an entire line (because user will have to press Enter anyway) and then decide what to do with it, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("product category: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String product_category = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Inventory(press enter key for 999): ");
    String pi_string = scanner.nextLine();
    int product_inventory = pi_string.isEmpty()?
        999:Integer.parseInt(pi_string);
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s, %d",
        product_category, product_inventory));
}
```